# unable to watch a bool variable in riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

i am trying to watch a boolean variable in riverpod so i have the bellow code sample.

```
final isPro = StateProvider<bool>((_) => false);

class Example extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    bool testPro = watch(isPro); //this line returns error
    var totgleBool = context.read(isPro.notifier);

  
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          totgleBool.state = true;
        },
        child: Container(child: testPro ? Text("yes") : Text("no")));
  }
}
```

so i am getting the following error " The argument type 'StateProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderBase<Object?, "
Thanks.

Comment: the error is saying that you can't use this StateProvider<bool> try to remove bool

Comment: thanks @FatihaIMOUSSAINE, i just remove the bool now and i got a new error in line ... child: testPro ? Text("yes") ... which says "Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.
Try changing the condition."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
class Example extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) { // changed here
    bool testPro = ref.watch(isPro); 
    var totgleBool = context.read(isPro.notifier);

  
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          totgleBool.state = true;
        },
        child: Container(child: testPro ? Text("yes") : Text("no")));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks , i tried that and got "Undefined class 'WidgetRef'."  so i tried checking out the error and it seems WidgetRef is not supported in the flutter_riverpod: ^0.14.0+1 and above, because i am using flutter_riverpod: ^0.14.0+1

Comment: update to the last version or at least 1.0.0

Comment: i just did that. thank you